# ASP.net Radiobutton group spanning 2 columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, radio-button

I have radio buttons in 2 columns in a gridview. Radio buttons in each row is a group. On clicking the Save button, the event has to read the checked values in column 1 and store them in a pipe separated string and checked values in column 2 in another string.

In the page load event, I create the buttons dynamically (I have tried binding on the front end already) and also set unique ids for each control. All are Static mode. Radio buttons in each group have the same text and value.

```
rbCannot.ID = "rbCannotSelect" & i
rbCannot.GroupName = grpName 

rbMust.ID = "rbMustSelect" & i
rbMust.GroupName = grpName
```

In the click event:

```
For j As Integer = 0 To grdOptionRelations.Rows.Count - 1
    rbCannotID = "rbCannotSelect" & i
    rbCannot = CType(grdOptionRelations.Rows(j).Cells(0).FindControl(rbCannotID), RadioButton)
    If rbCannot.Checked Then valCannot += rbCannot.Attributes("value").ToString + "|"

    rbMustID = "rbMustSelect" & i
    rbMust = CType(grdOptionRelations.Rows(j).Cells(1).FindControl(rbMustID), RadioButton)
    If rbMust.Checked Then valMust += rbMust.Attributes("value").ToString + "|"

    If rbCannot.Checked Then Response.Write("rbCannot " & rbCannot.Text & " " & rbCannot.Checked.ToString & vbCrLf)
    If rbMust.Checked Then Response.Write("rbMust " & rbMust.Text & " " & rbMust.Checked.ToString & vbCrLf)

    i += 1
  Next
```

Upon clicking the save button, I'm getting a null ref exception on the line "If rbCannot.Checked..."

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need any other information. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: when do you add radio button to gridview?

Comment: Resolved this. I moved the call to the BindData sub to the Init event instead of the page load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this. I moved the call to the BindData sub to the Init event instead of the page load event.